Azure Dev Ops Board Ticket Rich Text Formatting (indentation)
Scope
Rich text Formatting in azure-dev-ops-boards tickets
Issue
Rich text editor feature at the bottom of each text area like Description section.
When there is a lot of formatted text in the Description section on a smaller device like 14 inch macbook screen or 24 inch external monitor with 1080p resolution at best, one cannot easily use the Rich text editor features like indent left or right without scrolling to the bottom of the screen, while blind as the text you want to indent is out of visible screen area. Is there a keyboard shortcut to indent text in and out ?

Hi @Shahjahan Ravjee, have you checked the answer below and followed the feature request I created? Did it help you?

Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT thanks for your comment and creating the FR.

Yes, there are some keyboard shortcuts, specific to your OS.  Here are the ones for mac: macOS shortcuts.

Currently, there isn't default keyboard shortcut can be used to increase/decrease indent in work item.
I have submitted a feature request Add keyboard shortcuts for indent increment/decrement to product team, you can follow it, submit a vote and addd some comments. Voting and comments helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.

I have since being relentless, trying to find the keyboard shortcut, that's not documented anywhere as far a I looked.
Then I found the keyboard combination by chance. I have found the one for Mac, haven't got access to try using Windows. There is a caveat that this works for Bullets and Number List only.
To Indent Press : Tab
To UnIndent Press : Shift+Tab
